# Center OpenStreetMap at Location defined in specific Projection

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

```
 <body onload="init_gis()">
      <div id="map" style="height:750px"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">


var config = {

    init_lonlat : new OpenLayers.LonLat(363273.29099999997,5770864.300999998),
    maxExtent:  new OpenLayers.Bounds(363052,5770362,363467,5771122)
};




window.Proj4js = {
    Proj: function(code) {
      return proj4(Proj4js.defs[code]);
    },
    defs: proj4.defs,
    transform: proj4
  };
  // Definition comes from http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31466/
  proj4.defs["EPSG:31466"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=6 +k=1 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs";



  var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
  var german_projection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:31466");

map = new OpenLayers.Map({
  div:"map",
  projection: mercator,
  units: "m",
  maxResolution: 2
  //maxExtent:  config.maxExtent
});

function init_gis() {


  map.addLayers([
   new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()
   ]);



   console.log(config.init_lonlat);

   var transformation = config.init_lonlat.transform(german_projection,mercator); 
   map.setCenter(transformation,14);

   console.log(transformation);
}







  </script>
  </body>
```

I have: a location in the projection EPSG:31466 (`new OpenLayers.LonLat(363273.29099999997,5770864.300999998`), this is somewhere in Germany close to the dutch Border.

I want: to open OpenStreetMap and to center it at the respective Location.

I get: OpenStreetMap centered in eastern Greenland
If I uncomment `maxExtent: config.maxExtent` OpenStreetMap centered somewhere in the sea close to Ecuador.

What can I do / What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues.

1). Those bounds do not look correct. If you look at [spatial ref.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31466/) for that projection, you will see that the projected bounds are: `2490547.1867, 5440321.7879, 2609576.6008, 5958700.0208`.

Your input, 363273 is way outside of these bounds. Using Postgis,

```
select st_astext(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(363273, 5770864), 31466), 4326));
```

I transformed this to 4326, which gives, `POINT(-22.9771108554878 48.2922653479211)`, which is obviously nowhere near Germany, as it is in the North Atlantic somewhere.

If you add a 2 in front of your x coordinate, eg, 2363273, then you get, `POINT(4.00604395167782 52.0546272174417)` which is actually in the sea off the coast of Holland, better, but still outside of the bounds for Germany, which starts from 2490547, as stated bove.

2). Open Street Map uses 3857 as its projection, so once you have got the correct input coordinates in 31466, you will need to convert to 3857, not 4326.